# How to change ProgressBar values in another WPF thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am making a program that reads 1 file and writes it to another file, and the main thing is to make a `ProgressBar` there that will show progress, but when it starts, it swears that `ProgressBar` and the `charCount` variable that reads how many characters in a text file are in another stream. I used `Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>` and the program worked but now it hangs until this thread finishes its job.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(
            () =>
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    while (progBar.Value < charCount)
                    {
                        progBar.Value++;
                        Thread.Sleep(100);

                    }
                });
            });
thread.Start();
```

(`progBar`: `ProgressBar` name, `charCount`: stores the number of characters in a text file).

here is a piece of that code. It's strange that the same code without `Dispatcher` worked in Windows Forms and changed the value of the `ProgressBar` without hanging. Here it either freezes if you put `Sleep()`, or instantly changes the value of `ProgressBar` without `Sleep()`.

I need that while the program is running, the second thread that I create has the `ProgressBar` value so that the bar fills up without braking the main program.

UPD: I have to use the Thread method.

Here is what the code should look like

```
Thread thread = new Thread(
            () =>
            {
                while (progBar.Value < charCount)
                {
                    progBar.Value++;
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            });
        thread.Start();
```

Comment: What .NET platform are you targeting? .NET 7?

Comment: Besides that you should not directly create a Thread, the straightforward solution here is to move Dispatcher.Invoke inside the loop: `while (...) { Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progBar.Value++); Thread.Sleep(100); }`. And never call Thread.Sleep in the UI thread, e.g. inside a Dispatcher action.

Comment: And you would of course just use a timer, i.e. a DispatcherTimer in WPF.

Comment: With binding it would just work.... Also there is many answersto o similar questions using Progress<T>

Answer (score 0):

Move the Dispatcher call into the loop body. Otherwise the loop - including the Thread.Sleep call - is executed in the UI thread, which will block all UI updates.

here is a sample code to demonstrate how to read from 1 file and write to another file with a progress presentation. you can change it based on your need

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.txt"))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
    {
        int charCount = (int)reader.BaseStream.Length;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        int read;

        while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            bytesRead += read;

            if (updateCounter++ % 100 == 0)
            {
                int progress = (int)((double)bytesRead / charCount * 100);
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    progBar.Value = progress;
                }));
            }
        }
    }
});

thread.Start();
```

Comment: This is not a matter of Invoke vs BeginInvoke, but just where the Dispatcher is called. Dispatcher.Invoke never blocks the UI thread.

Comment: yes. you are right. we can add `if (updateCounter++ % 100 == 0)` before `Dispatcher` call to update progress bar less frequently to avoid blocking. i will update the code